# Passing parameters from servlet to servlet using HTTP POST

Tags: servlets

How do I pass parameters from ServletOne to ServletTwo using a HTTP POST through URL intead of using HTTP GET in the servlet?

For example: http://localhost/ServletOne?username=test

If the above link is accessed, in ServletTwo, username test will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You've a problem in your class design. The `ServletTwo` has apparently some code which needs to be reused in `ServletOne`. You need to refactor that code into a separate Java class. Once done that, all you need to do is to just import/use that Java class in both servlet classes the usual Java way.