# Passing parameters from one to other servlet using POST

Tags: json, servlets

How do I pass parameters from ServletOne to ServletTwo using a HTTP POST through URL?

For example: http://localhost/ServletOne?username=test

If the passing of parameters is successful, a JSON text will appear in the JSP page.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  Servlets process HTTP requests, they don't communicate with each other.  Are you trying to do a redirect for ServletOne to ServletTwo?  Please give a better example of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Provide more detail if you can.  I'm not entirely sure what you are asking.  Are these servlets running on the same server or are they separated?

Comment: Duplicate of [Passing parameters from servlet to servlet using HTTP POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032379/passing-parameters-from-servlet-to-servlet-using-http-post)  If you can't find your previously asked questions, click at the nickname (user448402) at top bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ServletOne and ServletTwo are running on the same server you can just use a foward.  ServletTwo will then have access to the query parameters from ServletOne.  Is that what you are asking?

For example:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {

    req.getRequestDispatcher("ServletTwo").forward(req,res);

}
```

If ServletOne and ServletTwo are running on different servers then you will have to code an HTTP POST request in ServletOne to call ServletTwo.